How can I edit predefined questions to Facebook page in Messenger?
I've read old replies, but they don't work now.
Can anyone tell me how to change default questions in Messenger please.

Enter the Meta Business Suite website. On the navigation on the side, select the page that you want to modify and click Inbox. On the top area, you will find Automations:

Scroll down and edit Frequently Asked Questions. Here you can add, edit, and remove questions that questions users will see on their end when they chat your Facebook Page.
